# OxyPlot: Is there a way to add checkboxes to legend in order to show and hide series?

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

Essentially what the question said. Is there a way to add checkboxes to the legend of the OxyPlot for each series and allow unchecking and checking in order to show and hide the series for that selected one.

My current oxyplot in XAML that works well (doing alot of things in code) is as follows:

```
<oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model}"/>
```